# DC/OS has three roles, they are master, slave, slave_public, why can't put them on one host?

Tags: dcos

I just investigate DC/OS, I find that DC/OS has three roles:master, slave, slave_public, I want to deploy a cluster which can host  master, slave or slave_public roles on one host, but currently I can't do that.

I want to know that why can't put them on one host when designed. If I do that, could I get some suggestions?

I just have the idea. If I can't do, I'll quit using DCOS, I'll use mesos and marathon.

Is there someone has the idea with me? I look forward to the reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, and things are actually being worked on to re-enforce that an machine is [installed with only one role](https://github.com/dcos/dcos/pull/303) because things break with more than one.

If you're trying to demo / experiment with DC/OS and you only have one machine, you can use Virtual Machines or Docker to partition that one machine into multiple machines / parts which you can install DC/OS on. [dcos-vagrant](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant) and [dcos-docker](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-docker) can help you there.

As far as installing though, the configuration for each of the three roles is incompatible with one another. The "master" role causes a whole bunch of pieces of software to be started / installed on a host (Mesos-DNS, Mesos master, marathon, exhibitor, zookeeper, 3dt, adminrouter, rexray, spartan, navstar among others) which listen on various ports. The "slave" role causes a machine to have a mesos-agent (mesos renamed mesos-slave to mesos-agent, hence the disconnect) configured and started on the agent. The mesos-agent is configured to control / most ports greater than 1024 to tasks which are launched by mesos frameworks on the agent. Several of those ports are used by services which are run on masters, resulting in odd conflicts and hard to fix bad behavior.

In the case of running the "slave" and "slave_public" on the same host, those two conflict more directly, because both of them cause mesos-agent to be run on the host, with slightly different configuration. Both the mesos-agent (the one configured with the "slave" role and the one with the "slave_public" role are configured to listen on port 5051. Only one of them can use it though, so you end up with one of the agents being non-functional.

Answer (score 0):

DC/OS only supports running a node as either a master or an agent(slave). You are correct that Mesos does not have this limitation. But DC/OS is more than just a Mesos/Marathon. To enable all the additional features of DC/OS there are various components built around Mesos and Marathon. At times these components behave differently whether they are running on a master or an agent and at other times the components that exist on a master may or may not exist on an agent or vice versa. So running a master and an agent on the same node would lead to conflicts/issues.

If you are looking to run a small development setup before scaling the solution out to a bigger distributed system [DC/OS Vagrant](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant) might be a good starting point.